# A wee bit confused about ASP.NET MVC Areas routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

If I have the following route defined in my only area:-

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Search_default",
    "Search/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new {controller = "Search", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
```

and I have the following action methods in the `SearchController`...

```
public ViewResult Index(string query, string prefs) {..}
public PartialViewResult Foo(SearchPreferences searchPreferences) { .. }
```

what would the expected ROUTES be, if a person was to manually type the route in their browser?

(I'm getting confused with the route AREA and the route CONTROLLER names .. seeing if they are expected to exist in the url or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following routes would resolve:

```
/Search => SearchController.Index(null, null)
/Search/Search => SearchController.Index(null, null)
/Search/Search/Index => SearchController.Index(null, null)
/Search/Search/Index/1 => SearchController.Index(null, null) // id maps to nothing

/Search/Search/Foo => SearchController.Foo(new SearchPreferences { })
/Search/Search/Foo/1 => SearchController.Foo(new SearchPreferences { id = 1 })
```

Comment: Cheers ;) this is *exactly* what I was afraid of .. Search is always listed TWICE in those routes.. which was why I was consistently getting 404's. And when i {controller} it worked .. but I was unsure if this was expected. Cheers!